# Moment.js returning wrong date

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to use moment to convert Date-Time for October 29th, 2013 with this format

```
2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z
```

However when I do this

```
moment('2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z').format("MMM Do, YYYY")
```

It returns **October 28th, 2013** when it should return **October 29th, 2013**

If you have some ideas on how I can solve this issue, please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want the time in utc, use:

```
moment.utc('2013-10-29T00:00:00.000')
```

As @MattJohnson pointed out, using the `moment` constructor will translate it to local time. Instead (if you don't want to use the `utc` method), you can replace the `Z` with `+0`. See options for string date/time http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: It *does* recognize the `Z`, but if you pass it on the `moment` constructor, it translates from UTC to local time.  Calling with `moment.utc` will place the *result* in UTC, in addition to assuming the input value is UTC.  So, what you wrote is just fine, but you could also pass the `Z` here, or do `.utc()` from what the OP originally wrote.

Comment: It also seems as though using the +0 offset will not translate it to local time.

Answer (score 8):

You can adjust the timezone settings by doing this:

```
moment('2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z').zone(0).format("MMM Do, YYYY");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BBQgL/)

Going to go ahead and add Matt's suggestion as well, since it is more semantic.

```
moment('2013-10-29T00:00:00.000Z').utc().format("MMM Do, YYYY");
```

Comment: This will *work*, but has a slightly different contextual meaning.  You might consider replacing `.zone(0)` with `.utc()`.  You still get a +1 from me. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson very good point. That's what I get for just skipping to the part in the documentation that mentioned timezones...

Comment: This is the best answer, in my opinion, since momentjs recognizes the 'Z' anyway. Why bother to perform string manipulation to remove the 'Z', as the currently accepted answer by @JeffStorey states.