# Formatting momentjs date-time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

Hi everyone I have looked at a few SO questions but have yet to find a solid answer to my problem. Question I have already looked at include:

- [Moment.js returning wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648688/moment-js-returning-wrong-date)
- [Moment JS - parse UTC and convert to Local and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782732/moment-js-parse-utc-and-convert-to-local-and-vice-versa)

My question is the following:

I have a basic time selector with times ranging from 4:00am - 8:00pm. I want to use the time selected along with a hard-coded date to format something that looks like this:

```
"2015-05-03T04:00:00"
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
time = moment("2015/05/09 " + filterText, "America/New_York")
console.log(time.format())
```

Where filterText is the string passed in by the select: `"4:00AM"`

How can i construct something that looks like: `"2015-05-09T04:00:00"` ?

As of now I am getting the following, which is way off: `"2015-02-27T08:20:00+00:00"`

When I remove the timezone I get something that is closer, but the time is not changing:

```
time = moment("2015/05/09 " + filterText)
console.log(time.format())
"2015-05-09T08:00:00-07:00" <--- remains at 7:00 even if filterText is 8:00 or 9:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
time = moment("2015/05/09 " + filterText);
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: this works well, but how can i determine am or pm? Say the filterText is 8:00AM - what would be the corresponding formatted string? What if it was 8:00PM - what would be the corresponding string?

Comment: You may use "hh" instead of "HH", but this will not show "AM" or "PM". What is your target format?

Comment: moment("2015/05/09 8:00 PM").format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss") returns "2015-05-09T20:00:00".

Comment: Thank you @simonmysun - that wrked. I needed to add a space between the time and am/pm. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should [specify a format string when parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
time = moment("2015-05-09 " + filterText, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmA");
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```

From the moment.js docs

> **Warning:** Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in some browsers will not work in other browsers.
>
> For consistent results parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String + Format.

If you don't pass a format string, you *may* get the correct results, or maybe not.  You will see the following message in the console log:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

Also, you probably don't need to pass the time zone for this purpose.  However, if you id need it to be time zone specific, that would be the wrong way to do it.  The `moment` function doesn't take a time zone parameter. You would need to use the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) addon, and pass it to the `tz` function, like this:

```
time = moment.tz("2015-05-09 " + filterText, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mmA", "America/New_York");
console.log(time.format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss"));
```