# Moment - Difference between two EPOCH dates

Tags: date, datetime, momentjs

I have two dates in EPOCH value.

Open : `1579269496000`

Close : `1579270005225`

I want to get display different between two dates.
So difference = Close - Open = `<ddd> Days <hh> Hours <mm> Mins <ss> Sec`.

I'm using Moment.js to convert the date but I don't see to substract EPOCH date using that.

```js
var c = new Date(close);
var o = new Date(open);

var seconds =enter code here (c.getTime() - o.getTime()) / 1000;

var ms = moment(close,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(open,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting momentjs date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29336358/formatting-momentjs-date-time)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this solves your concern.
First convert epoch value to the value supported by momentJS. Then you could get the difference in years and add that to the initial date; then get the difference in weeks and add that to the initial date again.

```
var moment = require("moment");

var a = "1582113418";
var b = "1582113444";

var aa = moment.unix(a); // converted value
var bb = moment.unix(b); // converted value

var days = bb.diff(aa, "days");
aa.add(days, "years");

var hours = bb.diff(aa, "hour");
aa.add(hours, "hours");

var seconds = bb.diff(aa, "seconds");

console.log(days + " days " + hours + " hours " + seconds + " seconds");
```

Working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-shamir-0yuxq